# "hide" element when if-statement is true (similar to if > then)

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, hide

I have this code that adds a custom field to my products in woocommerce:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'shoptimizer_custom_author_field', 3 );
function shoptimizer_custom_author_field() { ?>
<?php if(get_field('author')) { ?>
<div class="cg-author"><?php the_field('author'); ?></div>
<?php }
}
```

Now I would want to add a condition to the if-statement that says "if field is not empty, hide product title".

The class for the product page product title seems to be "product_title".

Will be fascinating how this will look like once It's added into this piece of code above. I think it's not a big deal, but my comprehension ends with HTML and CSS sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you want to hide the product title if the custom field is not empty, you can use the following code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'shoptimizer_custom_author_field', 3);

function shoptimizer_custom_author_field() {
    if (get_field('author')) {
        echo '<style>.product_title { display: none; }</style>';
    }
}
```

If you want to hide the product title if the custom field is empty, you can use the following code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'shoptimizer_custom_author_field', 3);

function shoptimizer_custom_author_field() {
    if ( ! get_field('author')) {
        echo '<style>.product_title { display: none; }</style>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Erhan! It seems in your code you deleted the line:

<div class="cg-author"><?php the_field('author'); ?></div>

and without this one the custom field wont be shown as it seems. Also it seems that your edit is missing the ?php parts.

Could you somehow bring your display: none approach together with the full code from above? 

Because I think then it will work! For me its hard to do so because I sadly know nothing about the rules.

:-) Hope to read back from you and thanks again!

Comment: Also! Yes! I want to hide the product title, when the custom field is not empty

Answer (score 0):

Just to conclude this thread, below anybody that seeks a similar answer can copy and paste the solution that worked for me:

```html
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {

    ?><style>
    h1.product_title.entry-title {
    display: none;
}

.cg-title h1.product_title.entry-title {
    display: block !important;
}
    }</style><?php
    
} );


add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'shoptimizer_custom_author_field', 3 );
  
function shoptimizer_custom_author_field() { ?>

<?php if(get_field('author')) { ?>
    
    <div class="cg-author"><h1><?php the_field('author'); ?></h1></div>
<?php }
else {?>
<div class="cg-title"><?php woocommerce_template_single_title(); ?> </div> 
<?php   
    }
}
```